# How to assign a click function to a group

Tags: jquery, css, image, function, click

I have two lines of color swatches that are identical. One set is for a foreground color and the other the background. I need to be able to select one from each line. The code shown in my fiddle works on my computer, except I use actual images. I didn't know how to do that with fiddle.

When a color is clicked on, it should be highlighted to show it is selected. Again, this part works on my computer. The problem is that when I select a color from one row and then select a color from a different row, the first selected color is reset. I know that is because the jquery is looking at all of the images but I don't know how to group them so a color from each can be shown as selected.

If it makes a difference, I actually want this to work with inputs of type images but this was easier to implement while I worked through it so I chose that method. Would someone please explain what is needed? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/z589x191/1/)

```
    .imgStr {display:inline-block }
    .selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
    div.shadow { 
    border: 0px solid #3DA1D2;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    <div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    </div>

    $("img").click(function(){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `parent().parent()` to find the element in the same row

```js
      $("img").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
      });
```

```css
.imgStr {display:inline-block }
.selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
div.shadow { 
border: 0px solid #3DA1D2;
padding: 10px;
}

div.shadow:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
</div>
 
<div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
<div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is "unselecting" the previous selection.

```
$(".selected").removeClass("selected");
```

Maybe you should change to:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
```

Your images are already grouped up in a major `<div>`. Using the parent/find syntax will make jQuery to look only inside that group instead of the whole document root.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for just the code shown. But when I add another img above both groups, as shown, that first images gets selected and stays selected. It should not be selectable at all. There will be many other images on the page that should also not show as selected. So is there a way to limit the click function to just check those two groups? Here's how I changed the code:

```
    <div><img src="outside.img"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white"><img src="someimg.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
```